# Rest Template PUT method In Android

Tags: android, rest

1. I'm new to Android and Rest Template.I have developed a android
   screen and display JSON data using Rest Template GET method on my
   screen.My next step is to update some fields like edit name and add
   missing things and save back to the rest Template.

   public class MyPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {
       TextView tv;
       private Listcp = new ArrayList<>();

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_preferences);
       Resources resources = getResources();
       Log.d("Consumer pojo", "onCreate:");
       new HttpRequestTask().execute();



   }
   private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ConsumerProfile>{



       @Override
       protected ConsumerProfile doInBackground(Void... params) {
           try {

               final String url = "http://192.168.1.213:9001/consumer/local/"+LoginFragment.CONSUMEROBJECT.getId();
               RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
               ConsumerProfile cp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ConsumerProfile.class);

               return cp;
           }catch (Exception e){
               Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(),e );

           }
           return null;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(ConsumerProfile cp){
           super.onPostExecute(cp);
           Log.d("cppppppppppppppppppppp", "onPostExecute: " + cp.getId());

           TextView fname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editfname);
           TextView mname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editmname);
           TextView lname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editlname);
           TextView nname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editnname);
           TextView dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editdob);
           TextView status=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editstatus);
           TextView homeAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edithomeAddr);
           TextView workAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editworkAddr);
           TextView income=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editincome);
           fname.setText(cp.getFirstName());
           mname.setText(cp.getMiddleName());
           lname.setText(cp.getLastName());
           nname.setText(cp.getNickName());
           dob.setText(cp.getDob());
           status.setText(cp.getStatus());
           homeAddress.setText(cp.getHomeAddress());
           workAddress.setText(cp.getWorkAddress());
           income.setText(cp.getIncome());
   ```

   }
   }[This Screen is for Get Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hdwo.png)
2. This is what I did Up to Now.
3. This code is for Get method.
4. It'll display The screen like in image.

---

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"><![CDATA[

        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >



    ]]>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="firstName"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editfname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="middleName"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editmname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="lastName"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editlname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="nickName"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editnname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dob"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editdob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="status"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editstatus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="homeAddress"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edithomeAddr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="workAddress"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editworkAddr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="income"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editincome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Update Preferences"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

1. This is my layout.
2. Actually what I'm trying to do is Get User Information and Edit Information and save back to the same end point.
3. When the user select Update button Then it I'll Display the Updated Screen.
4. Any help Appreciated.
5. Anyone Provide code for that.
6. Thankful to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.http.HttpResponseCache;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.R;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.pojo.Consumer;
import com.nusecond.suredeal.app.suredeal.pojo.ConsumerProfile;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class MyPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    TextView tv;
    TextView fname,mname,lname,nname,dob,status,homeAddress,workAddress,income;
    private  String FName,MName,LName,NName,Dob,Status,HomeAddress,WorkAddress,Income;
    private List<ConsumerProfile>cp = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_preferences);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Log.d("Consumer pojo", "onCreate:");
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
        addListenerOnButton();



    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        //final String url = "http://192.168.1.213:9001/consumer/local/"+LoginFragment.CONSUMEROBJECT.getId();
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FName=fname.getText().toString();
                MName=mname.getText().toString();
                LName=lname.getText().toString();
                NName=nname.getText().toString();
                Dob=dob.getText().toString();
                Status=status.getText().toString();
                HomeAddress=homeAddress.getText().toString();
                WorkAddress=workAddress.getText().toString();

                new HttpUpdateTask().execute();
               // Toast.makeText(addListenerOnButton(),"UpdatedSuccessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(MyPreferences.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    }

    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ConsumerProfile>{



        @Override
        protected ConsumerProfile doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                final String url = "http://192.168.1.213:9001/consumer/local/"+LoginFragment.CONSUMEROBJECT.getId();
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                ConsumerProfile cp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ConsumerProfile.class);

                return cp;

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(),e );

            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ConsumerProfile cp){
            super.onPostExecute(cp);
            Log.d("cppppppppppppppppppppp", "onPostExecute: " + cp.getId());

            fname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editfname);
             mname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editmname);
             lname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editlname);
             nname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editnname);
             dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editdob);
             status=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editstatus);
             homeAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edithomeAddr);
             workAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editworkAddr);
             income=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editincome);
            fname.setText(cp.getFirstName());
            mname.setText(cp.getMiddleName());
            lname.setText(cp.getLastName());
            nname.setText(cp.getNickName());
            dob.setText(cp.getDob());
            status.setText(cp.getStatus());
            homeAddress.setText(cp.getHomeAddress());
            workAddress.setText(cp.getWorkAddress());
            income.setText(cp.getIncome());
            //FName=fname.getText().toString();


        }







    }
private class HttpUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ConsumerProfile>{

    @Override
    protected ConsumerProfile doInBackground(Void... params) {
       try {
           final String url = "http://192.168.1.213:9001/consumer/local/" + LoginFragment.CONSUMEROBJECT.getId();
           RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
           ConsumerProfile consumerProfile = new ConsumerProfile();




          // String m=FName;
           consumerProfile.setFirstName(FName);

           fname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editfname);
           Log.d(" llllllllllllll", "doInBackground: " + FName);
           consumerProfile.setMiddleName(MName);
           consumerProfile.setLastName(LName);
           consumerProfile.setNickName(NName);
           consumerProfile.setDob(Dob);
           consumerProfile.setStatus(Status);
           consumerProfile.setHomeAddress(HomeAddress);
           consumerProfile.setWorkAddress(WorkAddress);
           consumerProfile.setDob(Income);

           restTemplate.put(url,consumerProfile);
           Log.d("ettttttttttttttt", "doInBackground: ");

           return consumerProfile;
       }catch (Exception e){
           Log.e( "consumer", e.getMessage(),e);
       }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```